# print pattern in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to print pattern like this, but it prints like second one?

```
    * 
   * * 
  * * * 
 * * * * 
* * * * *
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ0jK.png) -- here is my script

```
* 
   * * 
  * * * 
 * * * * 
* * * * *
```

Comment: Please add your code directly in the question as a code block, rather than as an image.

Comment: Also please check that you've shown the actual output you are getting - is it as shown, or are all the lines showing a `*` as the first character?

Comment: I added my code directly but there was errors for share and i couldnt solve it. 

set serveroutput on format wrapped after this problem solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine:

```
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. 5 LOOP
    FOR j IN i .. 4 LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(' ');
    END LOOP;
    FOR j IN 1 .. i LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('* ');
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

It outputs:

```
    * 
   * * 
  * * * 
 * * * * 
* * * * *
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9TF6GtkV)

Whatever IDE you are using may be stripping the leading whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

The output you've shown is a bit confusing, because if the first line is losing its leading whitespace then the rest of them should be too. But it depends on your client, as MTO said.

If you are using SQL*Plus (and similar) then you may just need to do:

```
set serveroutput on format wrapped
```